# bootstrap accordion : how to collapse all at a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, twitter-bootstrap-3

is there any option to collapse all the accordion when click on open or any other heading ?

for example click one the second heading all accordion should collapse. 
is it possible ?

**DEMO**  http://plnkr.co/edit/OxbVII?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is with your `accordion-toggle` links.

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" href="#">
```

Should be

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
```

Notice the `data-target` is not needed it instead goes into the `href` but the `data-parent` is added.  Needs to be done for all three links.

Example

http://plnkr.co/edit/VY7ETh?p=preview

Comment: @bboymaanu please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved. Thanks